# Filter visits to a site generated by "Top Sites" feature of some browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter, filtering

In [this answer to a Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/got-woot-badge-unfairly-with-safari-4/15380#15380), Jeff states that he has fixed the problem where  visits created by the "Top Sites" feature in Safari were counted for the Fanatic and Enthusiast badges.

My question is: how can this be done? **How I programatically tell a "top sites" visit and a regular visit apart?**

I'm looking for a general solution, although I would like to implement code that differentiates between those visit types in C# for an ASP.NET MVC site.

*NOTE: I'm not quite sure how to tag this question. If you have any ideas, please retag!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just looked at the headers that safari issues on the request and you can see an x-purpose: preview value. Check for this header to avoid false positives on visits:

```
GET http://www.yahoo.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yahoo.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16
X-Purpose: preview
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head here, couldn't it be that this "Fanatic-badgecounter" only counts when you've requested at least **more than one different page** in one day?